# double x-axis in R native plot, one for double frequency and the second for Dates

Tags: r, x-axis

I am using native R plot function to genertae graphics.  looking to add a double x-axis on same plot. One holds doubles and the other x-axis holds Date object.  I am using the following commands but they dont seem to work.

**First x-axis:**

```
axis.Date(1,at=seq(min(x$Date),na.rm=TRUE,max(x$Date),na.rm=TRUE,by="2 years"),format ="%Y-%m-%d",col.axis="white", cex=1)
```

**Second x-axis:**

```
axis(1,at=seq(min(f), max(f), by = 0.1), col.axis="white", cex=1)
```

The parameters for the R native plot:

```
x11()                                                                                    
 par(mfrow=c(1,1),oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0) )
```

Result is only Dates on x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

**Up front**: dual axes can easily be mis-used by mis-representing the data and/or ranges. It's *easy* for eyes to misconstrue correlation or relationships based on imperfect axis decisions. For scatter plots (such as below), I'm not a fan and tend to avoid them ... but I do use them under very controlled circumstances, as they can provide visual correlation of relative trends.

When I must do it, I'm a fan of using color as a way to more strongly tie points (or lines) with particular axes, though of course this does not work as well with color-impaired readers.

Given that preface ...

I believe the easiest way to handle multiple axes in base-R is to use `par(new=TRUE)` between plots. Here's an example:

```r
par(mar = c(4,4,4,4) + 0.1)

plot(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars, las = 1)

par(new = TRUE)

dat <- data.frame(dat = Sys.Date() + 0:5, y = 1:6)
plot(y ~ dat, data = dat, ann = FALSE, yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", pch = 16, col = "red")
axis.Date(3, dat$dat[1], col = "red", line = 1)
axis(4, col = "red", line = 1, las = 1)
```

[image: base R graphic with dual axes]

Other differentiating techniques include shapes or line-types (if lines) specific to each side, and adding those as clear markers on the secondary axes.

The use of `par(new=TRUE)` simply allows the next plot command to *not* reset/clear the canvas before starting over. This means that the subsequent plotting functions have no knowledge of what is existing. From `?par`:

```
     'new' logical, defaulting to 'FALSE'.  If set to 'TRUE', the next
          high-level plotting command (actually 'plot.new') should _not
          clean_ the frame before drawing _as if it were on a *_new_*
          device_.  It is an error (ignored with a warning) to try to
          use 'new = TRUE' on a device that does not currently contain
          a high-level plot.
```

It doesn't work well with all plotting mechanisms (certainly nothing `grid` or `ggplot2`), and anything that might be sensitive to `mar`gins or `oma` or other `par`ameters should be tested carefully with various ranges of data.

I intentionally used `line=1` to "bump out" the top/right axes, another way to set them apart. Frankly, I often do that for the bottom/left (primary) axes as well, it can be aesthetically preferred ... but it's an option and not required for this technique to at least start the process.